# Can Glass Mapper Sc create instance of mapping interface?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8

I am using Interface Mapping Concept in my project because my Sitecore items use/inherit multiple base templates. This worksnice but sometimes I need to create object that implements my template interface(ie. I want to add item to Sitecore) to do that I am forced to create a class that implements desired interface and than create object. Do I need to do that? Is there something in Glass.Mapper.Sc that returns proxy object I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this.. why is it a problem to create a class implementing the interface Maybe it helps if you show some code of what you would like to do.

Comment: @RvanDalen It is not a problem to create a class that implements my interface. I am wondering if I need to do that, because Glass creates proxy object internally, what I have asked was: can I get proxy object form glass so I do not need to create classes.

Comment: lukasz, do you mean created dynamically when you instance an object? I think what you are referring to is an object relational mapper,  have a look a GlassMapper :) http://glass.lu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried to imagine a possible scenario where you would use Castle's ProxyGenerator to generate an object based on one or more Interfaces. But I suspect you will run into problems because Glass's SitecoreService will expect a TypeConfiguration to work with, which you will not have if you generate a Proxy.

However, creating a new item using an Interface should be possible like this:

```
var service = new SitecoreService("master");
var newItem = service.Create<IArticle, ISitecoreItem>(parentItem, "New item name");
//populate the properties
newItem.Introduction = "In the beginning there was a...";
service.Save(newItem);
```

ISitecoreItem is the type of the parent, you can use a common Interface for that. IArticle is the type of the new item.

I havent tested this, but looking at the source code of Glass I do not see why this shouldnt work.

Comment: Thank you. Work like a charm!